# Vim copy and concatenate the lines

Tags: vim, range, lines

I got a file that looks like this:

```
G:\some_folder
    file1.avi
    file2.wav
E:\some_folder2
    fileABC.avi
    fileDEF.wav
```

I would like to transfer the file into:

```
G:\some_folder
G:\some_folder  file1.avi
G:\some_folder  file2.wav
E:\some_folder2
E:\some_folder2 fileABC.avi
E:\some_folder2 fileDEF.wav
```

So in other words this might work like this:
look for `^[A-Z]:` copy whole line and add it at the beginning to next lines till you find `^[A-Z]:`

is it possible to do that in VIM? If yes, how.

thank you
Radek

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would iterate over all lines with `:global`; Vim will position the cursor on the beginning of each line. Depending on which kind of line it is, I'd either yank the folder path, or paste it in front:

```
:%g/^/execute 'normal!' getline('.') =~ '^\S' ? 'y$' : 'P'
```